# Couldn't find the Oracle Data source in visual studio 2012 while adding the ado.net Entity Model

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller

This is my first time with MVC. When I am trying to add an ADO.net entity model then while creating a new connection I couldn't see my oracle database in the list of data source name. Only different type of Microsoft server is listed. What should I do to get the oracle database listed there too. When using simple database connection in the desktop application I could see the oracle database listed but not in this case. 
[image]

**The main problem is I couldn't connect entity data model to oracle database**

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install the Oracle Developer Tools, which is a surprisingly complicated process.
This is a rather old article, but I think this is still useful

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/07/18/connecting-to-oracle-from-visual-studio.aspx